# Oven/Food safe Filament?

Tags: filament, food

I just backed a 3d printer on kickstarter, called "Mooz", and I was wondering about some of the possible applications of it. I realized it would be cool/helpful to be make cookie models, and bake cookies to that shape. The cookies can be baked as low as around 250 °F, **So is there any food-safe and heat resistant filament that can withstand those temperatures?** (I know many filaments are printed above those temps anyways, but in my case I don't want them to even warp.) Google has failed me on this one, so I hope someone here can answer it for me!
-Thanks in advance :)

P.S. My 3d printer will have a heated bed, so it can print more types of filaments. The highest bed temp is 100 °C, and the highest hot end temp is 250 °C. I don't really mind using some sealant, but I'd rather not use something toxic like ABS.

P.P.S I'm a newbie to this stuff, so I apologize in advance if I asked a really stupid question.

Comment: You could possibly use printing, lost-wax casting, and silicone to make the mold. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost-wax_casting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to bake cookies inside a plastic mold; the plastic will smoke even if not melt. If you need to bake cookies use a cookie cutter made of plastic (your own design or copy) obviously printed on your new printer then bake normally. here is a [link from thingeverse](https://www.thingiverse.com/search/page:1?q=cookie&sa=&dwh=525a11237f7ad40) to get a cookie cutter .stl file

:) enjoy cutting cookies these holidays

Here is [another link](http://makefastworkshop.com/hacks/?p=20171116) from hacks from one person is making the same to show his idea.

Comment: I was thinking of more about PC, which has a http://https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycarbonate glass transition temperature of around 147 °C according to Wikipedia. The oven would be around 50 °F cooler than that temp, would it still smolder?

Comment: Sorry- I forgot to add that I could technically bake the cookies at as low as 250 °F, so would there be a filament for that temperature?

Comment: @Rafael No my friend, never try to use plastics for molding cookies or cook. Plastics are only used for storage and can be harmful if the plastic gets hot for long periods due chemicals (odor or smoke). Plastics becomes soft at lower temperatures of melting, so in this lapse the plastics release the odor that can be mixed with your food contaminating every thing. The kind of plastics for molding is silicon with food grade (clean of toxines).

Comment: There's obviously some 'safe' range of temperatures for 3d filaments. Baking aside, what's a general safest, hottest temperature for a plastic filament? The bed temp?

Comment: @Rafael Oh, this is another kind of question and I have the answer for each plastic. Please open that as new question.

Comment: I opened a new question here: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5013/what-are-the-safest-temperatures-to-heat-different-filaments-to